# NextJS _error.js not rendering for API routes? How else do to handle & log API errors consistently?

Tags: next.js, sentry

I've setup a custom `_error.js` hoping to capture to both regular page & API page errors.

Below is the full page. I've integrated Sentry and included the ENV variable in my environment.

However, it doesn't seem to trigger for `pages/api/*/**.js` pages. Only regular pages.

The middleware system is a bit ...lacking in the API routes. I'd like to avoid instantiating the Sentry middleware on every single API route.

I thought the `_error.js` page would apply to both types of pages. Am I missing another way to capture all API level errors?

```
import NextErrorComponent from "next/error";
import * as Sentry from "@sentry/node";

const Error = ({ statusCode, hasGetInitialPropsRun, err }) => {
  if (!hasGetInitialPropsRun && err) {
    // getInitialProps is not called in case of
    // https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/8592. As a workaround, we pass
    // err via _app.js so it can be captured
    Sentry.captureException(err);
  }

  return <NextErrorComponent statusCode={statusCode} />;
};

Error.getInitialProps = async ({ res, err, asPath }) => {
  const errorInitialProps = await NextErrorComponent.getInitialProps({
    res,
    err,
  });

  // Workaround for https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/8592, mark when
  // getInitialProps has run
  errorInitialProps.hasGetInitialPropsRun = true;

  // Running on the server, the response object (`res`) is available.
  //
  // Next.js will pass an err on the server if a page's data fetching methods
  // threw or returned a Promise that rejected
  //
  // Running on the client (browser), Next.js will provide an err if:
  //
  //  - a page's `getInitialProps` threw or returned a Promise that rejected
  //  - an exception was thrown somewhere in the React lifecycle (render,
  //    componentDidMount, etc) that was caught by Next.js's React Error
  //    Boundary. Read more about what types of exceptions are caught by Error
  //    Boundaries: https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html

  if (res?.statusCode === 404) {
    // Opinionated: do not record an exception in Sentry for 404
    return { statusCode: 404 };
  }
  if (err) {
    Sentry.captureException(err);
    await Sentry.flush(2000);
    return errorInitialProps;
  }

  // If this point is reached, getInitialProps was called without any
  // information about what the error might be. This is unexpected and may
  // indicate a bug introduced in Next.js, so record it in Sentry
  Sentry.captureException(
    new Error(`_error.js getInitialProps missing data at path: ${asPath}`)
  );
  await Sentry.flush(2000);

  return errorInitialProps;
};

export default Error;
```

Comment: have you managed to find an answer to this question by yourself ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, not one that I'm happy with.

For now I'm including Sentry in every try...catch as well as wrapping every API route. But official support is still lacking: https://sentry.io/for/nextjs/

Comment: thanks I am working on something similar, mays ask what you do for the client side ? are you wrapping ErrorBoundaries around you page or Component inside of App ?